# How can I force Mint to attempt to connect to a wifi network I just created?

Tags: linux-mint

Trying to get a bookshelf linux machine connected to the wifi. This machine used to be on a wired connection but that's not an option here. Got 4 other devices (mac, windows, android) connected to the wifi.

Steps taken:

1. turn wifi on in control panel, Network
2. go to Network Connections control panel
3. add a wifi connection (+, select Wifi, hit Create)
4. type in SSID of network (the network name, yes?), leave everything else as default
5. go to security select WPA2 Personal (confirmed this is same as router), type in password, show password to confirm
6. Hit OK/Create (don't remember rn)

Then I have to assume that Mint will attempt to connect, but nothing happens. There's no option to right click on the wifi network and connect to it. Rebooting the device isn't helping. Double clicking the network starts the edit dialog. There's no wireless icon in the system tray.

How do I force Mint to attempt to connect to this network? Is there some way to test the network creds?

Keep in mind I have no network connection. I tried joining a Bluetooth PAN but the device won't see my Android phone, so that didn't work. Running ethernet to the device would be a lot of work.

Mint 19. Perhaps I just need to reinstall Mint from a USB.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I made a hotspot. It may work for you. You have to use the command line
`nmcli connection up <connection name>`

Comment: I used `nmcli d status` to show my devices. See the wifi is "wlp3s0". Then ran `nmcli c up wlp3s0` and it said "unknown connection 'wlp3s0'". I don't get it.

Comment: @jcollum, you are getting it wrong, connection name == SSID/the network name , not device name (wlp3s0)

Comment: huh, I think I tried that but I'll give it another shot